# Next subsequent letter in the alphabet

Tags: alphabet

Getting the next letter of the alphabet is no problem in most programming languages I know. However, in LaTeX, it doesn't seem to be that trivial.

I have looked at [how to make 26 macros (here at stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952980/quick-way-to-make-26-macros-one-for-each-letter) but that question and its answers does not involve manipulations of the underlying unicode or something like that.

It is fine if the boundary case (e.g. the lowercase “z”) is not handled at all. I was thinking myself of something like the following:

```
\mydefalphabet abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \mydefalphabet
\mydefalphabetshifted bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza \mydefalphabetshifted
```

Can I return in this case the symbol at the shifted range when given the nonshifted range perhaps?

The envisioned command would be:

```
\newcommand\nextletter[1]{ 
}
```

And used as `$\nextletter{i}$` in math mode. I can then use `$\robotindex$` (equal to `i`) and `$\other{\robotindex}$` in my formulas (with `other` equivalent to `nextletter`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Approach 1

This works for miniscule letters in the `a-z` range and has an optional argument (the shifting amount).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\nextLetter}[2][1]{%
    \edef\numLet{\expandafter\number\expandafter`#2}%
    \edef\numNewLet{\number\numexpr\numLet+#1\relax}%
    \ifnum\numNewLet>122\relax%
        \edef\numNewLet{\number\numexpr\numNewLet-26\relax}%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\char\expandafter\numNewLet%
}
\def\robotindex{i}
\begin{document}
\nextLetter{a}%           a => b
\nextLetter{z}%           z => a
\nextLetter[13]{a}%       a => n
\nextLetter{\robotindex}% i => j
\end{document}
```

## Approach 2

This approach uses the macros `\myAlphabet` and `\myAlphabetShifted` to look for the “next” letter.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\myAlphabet{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\def\myAlphabetShifted{bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza}
\newcommand*{\nextLetter}[1]{%
    \StrPosition{\myAlphabet}{#1}[\myPosition]%
    \StrChar{\myAlphabetShifted}{\myPosition}%
}
\def\robotindex{i}
\begin{document}
\nextLetter{a}%           a => b
\nextLetter{z}%           z => a
\nextLetter{a}%           a => b
\nextLetter{\robotindex}% i => j
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both approaches work flawlessly! Especially the second one will be trivial for me to use also for Greek letters. It's now super easy to be consistent through my papers, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\robotindex}{i}
\newcommand{\nextletter}[1]{\expandafter\donextletter\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand{\donextletter}[1]{\ifnum`#1=122 \else\char\numexpr`#1+1\relax\fi}

\begin{document}
\nextletter{a}

\nextletter{\robotindex}

X\nextletter{z}X
\end{document}
```

The output is

> b
>   j
>   XX

Comment: @StephanLehmke Because I made a mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Alph{}`, `\alph{}` with a counter to get the corresponding alphabetic letter:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}%  \foreach is my preferred looping

\newcounter{CharNumber}% can probably do with out this, but I know this works.

\begin{document}
\noindent
\foreach \x in {1,...,26} {%
    \setcounter{CharNumber}{\x}%
    \Alph{CharNumber}%
}
\par\noindent
\foreach \x in {1,...,26} {%
    \setcounter{CharNumber}{\x}%
    \alph{CharNumber}%
}
\par\noindent
\foreach \x in {1,...,26} {%
    \setcounter{CharNumber}{\x}%
    \Roman{CharNumber}, %
}
\par\noindent
\foreach \x in {1,...,26} {%
    \setcounter{CharNumber}{\x}%
    \roman{CharNumber}, %
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This goes from numbers to letters, how can it be done the other way around? Something like this?
`\newcounter{CharNumber}
    \newcommand\nextletter[1]{
        \setcounter{CharNumber}{#1}
        \addtocounter{CharNumber}{1}
        \Alph{CharNumber}
    }`

(sorry for the formatting here in the comment section)